# Post did not show up in Close queue, voted in post

Tags: discussion

I recently came across a post [Make a graph in GIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/230090/make-a-graph-in-gis) that received close votes that appeared only the post itself and not in the close queue. I haven't seen any other posts in Meta that covered this question of mine.

[image]

I did have the option to vote via the post but not in the queue.

[image]

Why is it that the close vote was displayed in the post (at the time it had 1 close vote) however it did not appear in the Close queue?

Comment: It goes to a review queue "Note that even if a question is old and does not receive much attention, casting a close vote will put it into a review queue." http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3154/how-should-my-flagging-change-when-i-gain-the-ability-to-vote-to-close

Comment: @Mapperz I believe whyzar is saying that he can't see it in the review queue even though it has 3 close votes on it.  When I went to look it was in my review queue.

Comment: Likely Browser Cache lag then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the accepted answer to [A site option to delay appearance of questions in the close vote review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/284734/329733) which states there is a 15 minute delay before entering the review queue.

A Close or Reopen vote must have been there for at least 15 minutes before entering the review queue.  For Late Answer or Low Quality the post has to be at least 15 minutes old.